# Sessions php y cookies (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies

¿Las sesiones de php (laravel) pueden usarse o iniciarse si las cookies de un navegador estan deshabilitadas?

El problema es que cuando desactivo las cookies en mi navegador y envio un formulario me da el siguente error:
    TokenMisMatchException
    in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)

```
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)

at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in ShareErrorsFromSession.php (line 49)
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in StartSession.php (line 64)
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php (line 37)
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in EncryptCookies.php (line 59)
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))in Router.php (line 576)
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request))in Router.php (line 535)
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))in Router.php (line 513)
at Router->dispatch(object(Request))in Kernel.php (line 174)
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in ValidatePostSize.php (line 27)
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46)
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))in Kernel.php (line 149)
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))in Kernel.php (line 116)
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))in index.php (line 54)
```

Y cuando activo las cookies, la pagina siguiente al formulario funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Siguiendo este enlace, justo en esa sección se puede leer que algunas veces, cuando utilizamos formularios y queremos hacer nuestro propio "recorrido" de urls o sistema de formularios, será necesario desactivar el TOKEN a modo de excepción en el middleware que verifica la URL y conexion interna por seguridad para evitar redirecciones no autorizadas en formularios.

Comment: Gracias amigo! :)

Comment: Solamente agregue la ruta a VerifyCsrfToken.php la cual quedó como:

    protected $except = [
        //
     '/book'
    ];

Comment: Genial entonces. Me alegro que se solucionara :). No dudes en volver!